# How to change the thickness of WinUI progress ring?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I have a WinUI progress ring in my UWP C# XAML app like this

```
xmlns:winui="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"

<winui:ProgressRing
    Width="250"
    Height="250"
    Foreground="Green"
    IsIndeterminate="False"
    Maximum="60"
    Value="59" />
```

It looks like this

[image]

How do I make it thicker?

Comment: I am afraid there is no property that lets you change the thickness of the `ProgressRing`.  It's implemented as an animated visual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mm8 said, WinUI ProgressRing is implemented with [`AnimatedVisualPlayer`](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/ProgressRing/ProgressRing.xaml#L38), and it will [load play source](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/ProgressRing/ProgressRing.cpp#L222) in the code behind.

```
player.Source(winrt::make<AnimatedVisuals::ProgressRingIndeterminate>());
```

[`ProgressRingIndeterminate`](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/ProgressRing/AnimatedVisuals/ProgressRingIndeterminate.cpp) Lottie animation has not provide method to edit thickness. if you do want to this feature, please post your requirement in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml), and share link below, I will help to vote up.

Comment: That's really unfortunate. I would like to have a thickness property in a progress ring control. Looks like there's already an issue for this. An upvote would be appreciated: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3293